# Is it wrong to think of "memfd"s as accounted "to the process that owns the file"?

Tags: linux-kernel, out-of-memory, resources, shared-memory

https://dvdhrm.wordpress.com/2014/06/10/memfd_create2/

> Theoretically, you could achieve [`memfd_create()`] behavior without introducing new syscalls, like this:
>
> `int fd = open("/tmp", O_RDWR | O_TMPFILE | O_EXCL, S_IRWXU);`

(Note, to more portably guarantee a tmpfs here, we can use "`/dev/shm`" instead of "`/tmp`").

> Therefore, the most important question is why the hell do we need a third way?
>
> [...]
>
> - The backing-memory is accounted to the process that owns the file and is not subject to mount-quotas.

^ Am I right in thinking the first part of this sentence cannot be relied on?

The [memfd_create() code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/shmem.c#L3679) is literally implemented as an "[unlinked file living in [a] tmpfs which must be kernel internal](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/mm/shmem.c#L4254)". Tracing the code, I understand it differs in not implementing LSM checks, also memfds are created to support "seals", as the blog post goes on to explain. However, I'm extremely sceptical that memfds are *accounted* differently to a tmpfile in principle.

Specifically, when the [OOM-killer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html) comes knocking, I don't think it will account for memory held by memfds.  This could total up to 50% of RAM - the value of the [size= option for tmpfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt).  The kernel doesn't set a different value for the internal tmpfs, so it would use the default size of 50%.

So I think we can generally expect processes which hold a large memfd, but no other significant memory allocations, will not be OOM-killed.  Is that correct?

Comment: As far as OOM scores goes it seems to come down to [the kernel oom_badness function](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/mm/oom_kill.c?h=v4.19-rc3#n233). So I suspect if the memfd_create doesn't show up in a /proc/{pid}/map then its not counted. So the general answer is they could be killed, but they won't have a large score because of the memfd_create use. The memory for the fd can be shared across processes as multiple process can inherit/be sent, the same fd.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @danblack's answer:

The decision is based on `oom_kill_process()` (cleaned up a bit):

```
for_each_thread(p, t) {
        list_for_each_entry(child, &t->children, sibling) {
                unsigned int child_points;

                child_points = oom_badness(child,
                        oc->memcg, oc->nodemask, oc->totalpages);
                if (child_points > victim_points) {
                        put_task_struct(victim);
                        victim = child;
                        victim_points = child_points;
                        get_task_struct(victim);
                }
        }
}
```

(https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/oom_kill.c#L974)

Which depends on `oom_badness()` to find the best candidate:

```
child_points = oom_badness(child,
        oc->memcg, oc->nodemask, oc->totalpages);
```

`oom_badness()` does:

```
points = get_mm_rss(p->mm) + get_mm_counter(p->mm, MM_SWAPENTS) +
        mm_pgtables_bytes(p->mm) / PAGE_SIZE;
```

(https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/oom_kill.c#L233)

Where:

```
static inline unsigned long get_mm_rss(struct mm_struct *mm)
{
        return get_mm_counter(mm, MM_FILEPAGES) +
                get_mm_counter(mm, MM_ANONPAGES) +
                get_mm_counter(mm, MM_SHMEMPAGES);
}
```

(https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/mm/oom_kill.c#L966)

So it looks that it counts anonymous pages, which is what `memfd_create()` uses.

Comment: does this also count pages that are not mapped, but referenced by fds opened by the process?

Comment: I'm not sure what those would be. Is that cache?

Comment: For example, you could call memfd_create and write 4GB of data into there. I don't think that will be counted by the above metric, but it does represent memory that will be freed when the process dies

Comment: According to memfd_create(2): "Anonymous memory is used for all backing pages of the file.  Therefore, files created by memfd_create() have the same semantics as other anonymous memory allocations such as those allocated using mmap(2) with the MAP_ANONYMOUS flag". So that should count against MM_ANONPAGES.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, your understanding is generally correct.** The `memfd_create()` syscall creates an anonymous file. This file acts like a regular file but stays in RAM, not being linked to any specific filesystem [[1]](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man2/memfd_create.2.html). It means memory usage is directly accounted to the owning process, like other anonymous memory allocations as `malloc()` [[2]](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html). So when the allocation isn't tied to a filesystem or mount point, it's not included in quotas enforced at those levels.

The **OOM killer** primarily targets processes based on overall memory consumption and the impact they have on the system's total memory pressure, regardless of origin (e.g., *tmpfs*, *anonymous memory*)[[3]](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/linux-out-of-memory-killer). Yet, OOM killer does consider total memory usage, including memory-mapped files and anonymous memory.

When memory used by `memfd_create()` contributes to the overall memory footprint, when the process holding large allocations with `memfd_create()` and it has minimal other memory allocations, it's less likely to be targeted by the OOM killer solely because its total memory usage might still be considered lower compared to different processes.

The attitude for `memfd_create()` allocations being treated significantly differently from other `tmpfiles` in OOM killing is a result of how Linux accounts for and manages memory as a whole, rather than a specific mechanism the OOM killer that targets different allocation types [[4]](https://docs.kernel.org/mm/index.html).